# Installing Microsoft SEO Toolkit on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, iis

I used the Microsoft SEO Toolkit a while back and remember it being useful.

[Microsoft SEO Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/web/seo/)

I would like to install it on Windows 10, however the installation fails stating that IIS Version 7.0 or later is required. Windows 10 has IIS Version 10 but there is obviously some incompatibility.

As far as I know it is not possible to install an earlier version of IIS alongside Version 10.

Is there any way to install SEO Toolkit? Or can I only hope that the Toolkit will receive an update?

Comment: install a Win7 VM inside Windows 10 (Hyper-V) and use it here

Comment: @magicandre1981 I don't have a Win7 license.

Comment: there is a 90 da Win7 trial. recreate the VM again after the 90 day ended.

Answer (score 14):

It seems the SEO Toolkit suffers from the "assume the first digit is the version", and thus can't parse "10" as bigger than "7".  http://ridilabs.net/post/2015/12/11/Install-SEO-toolkit-on-Windows-10-and-Server-2012-R2.aspx suggests a solution:

- Open the Regedit.exe
- Visit the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp
- Change the Major Version attribute from 10 to 7
- Install the packages: [x64](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9695986) or [x86](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9695985)
- Get back to Regedit.exe
- Change back from 7 to 10

And I'm with the author of [this rant](http://forums.iis.net/t/1227963.aspx?IIS+SEO+Tool+Kit+fails+on+Windows+10+Pro) - it's a really lame cop-out to make us do this.

Comment: That fixed it for me. Doh!